# How can I run a console project from within a WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, console

I currently have a WPF project that has a button.
When you click on the button I intend on having a Console application launch. The console application is a project within the same application.
I am unclear how to properly run the console application as when i try the code below nothing happens(for now the code below is running automatically, without needing to click the button).

```
public void OpenTheConsoleApp() {
        TheConsoleApp.Program test = new TheConsoleApp.Program();
    }
```

The console app is as follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace TheConsoleApp
{
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void Test() {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
```

}

I need to open the console app by clicking a button on my WPF app.

Comment: You need to read about Process.Start() method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Now, if your WPF program depends on functionality of the console project, and the console project is also part of your VS solution for the WPF project, could you perhaps just turn the console app project into a class library? Alternatively, you can let the console app be a console app, but despite this also refer to it in your WPF project like a class library. This way, your WPF project can directly work with the (public) classes from the console project (you would structure your console app project in a way similar as what you would do with a class library plus an additional `main` method)

Comment: Also, note that user input/output should go through the user interface of the WFP app. There is no point to switch to a console app and yank the user away from the GUI to make him interact with a console window. In this sense, the code in your question shows a somewhat questionable approach. Your user interacts with the WPF app, so what would be the point of all those `Console.WriteLine` and `Console.ReadKey` anyway...? Let the WPF user interface deal with output and input of data...

Comment: @elgonzo the purpose of the Console app will later be to run selinium chrome drivers and scrape data + interact with a web page. But for now I need to be able to initiate my console app so I am testing with simple "hello world" code until the Console app is able to be launched.

Comment: @chronoxor thank you. Will this work seeing that the process is a project within the same VS project? (i added a console "project" into my main project.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't start a "project". You need to create an executable (.exe) to start. Build the console app and start the .exe in the output folder using `Process.Start`:

```
Process.Start(@"c:\your_project_dir\bin\Debug\ConsoleApp.exe");
```